# Mounting an AFP network volume eventually freezes my Yosemite System

Tags: network, smb, nas, afp

Ever since I upgraded to 10.10.2 shortly after boot my whole system becomes unusable.  Any app that interacts with the volume freezes up such as Finder.  Killing the Finder process does not fix the issue.  This happens when I mount my Synology NAS as an AFP volume.  Before 10.10.2 I could mount the same volume as AFP without issue.

After my system is up for a little while I see this repeated over and over in my system log

```
5/3/15 10:29:14.000 AM kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:    GetReconnectToken failed 32 /Volumes/Scotts Stuff
5/3/15 10:29:14.000 AM kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  doing reconnect on /Volumes/Scotts Stuff
5/3/15 10:29:14.000 AM kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  posting to KEA EINPROGRESS for /Volumes/Scotts Stuff
5/3/15 10:29:14.000 AM kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  Max reconnect time: 30 secs, Connect timeout: 15 secs for /Volumes/Scotts Stuff
5/3/15 10:29:14.000 AM kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  connect to the server /Volumes/Scotts Stuff
5/3/15 10:29:14.000 AM kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  Logging in with uam 8 /Volumes/Scotts Stuff
5/3/15 10:29:14.000 AM kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  Restoring session /Volumes/Scotts Stuff
5/3/15 10:29:14.000 AM kernel[0]: ASP_TCP ReplayPendingReqs: replaying slot 45 with reqID 64312 afpCmd 72 on so 0xffffff80469103d8
5/3/15 10:29:14.000 AM kernel[0]: ASP_TCP ReplayPendingReqs: replaying slot 46 with reqID 64313 afpCmd 72 on so 0xffffff80469103d8
5/3/15 10:29:14.000 AM kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  get the reconnect token
5/3/15 10:29:14.000 AM kernel[0]: ASP_TCP CancelOneRequest: cancelling slot 81 error 32 reqID 5797 flags 0x9 afpCmd 0x40 so 0xffffff80469103d8
```

My current work around is to mount it as SMB.  When mounted as SMB I don't have any issues.   However I would prefer to mount as AFP because sometimes I get some weird issues with iTunes when using SMB as my iTunes library is on my network storage device.

Comment: Might want to update to 10.10.3 and see if the issue goes away. If it doesn't, I'd try to see which files ate being accessed when it locks up: ps aux | grep -i Finder | head -n 1 | col | cut -f 2 | cut -d' ' -f 1 | xargs -I {} sudo opensnoop -v -p {} | tee -a ~/Desktop/logfile.txt

Comment: I'm current running with 10.10.3 and still see the issue.  Next time I see the issue I'll try to grep the process.